# MSVCR110.dll missing even when reinstalling Visual C++

Tags: windows, windows-10, dll, visual-c++

After getting "the code execution cannot proceed because MSVCR110.dll was not found" error when trying to launch certains applications, I reinstalled `Microsoft Visual C++ 2012` and restarted. Didn't work. I then installed `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015, 2017 and 2019` [from Microsoft website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) and restarted. Didn't work: still getting same error message.

No matter what I do, `MSVCR110.dll` never exists in `C:\Windows\System32`.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Did you install Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 update 4? Also, 32 or 64-bit? Try also http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: Yes I did visit that particular page, and I downloaded + installed `vcredist_x64.exe` then restarted. Still the same error...

Comment: If the products you are installing or using are 32-bits, the right folder is `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. Use a 64-bit file-manager to have a look in this folder, since 32-bit programs will see `SysWOW64` as named `System32` and aren't capable of seeing `System32` at all. (Microsoft's solution to mixing 32- and 64-bits has a few gotchas.) Also, if you are using another antivirus than Defender, verify the quarantined files.

Comment: Try to see if you are using a DEBUG version of your executable, if it is possible to migrate to Release, this has already happened to me with Intel Fortran, but this has been going on for a few years.

Comment: Which applications are giving this error? Can you list them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never had problems with installing the Microsoft Visual C++ redistributables. Therefore, I believe that there is a special situation on your PC which keeps the setup programs from placing that files into `c:\windows\system32` or `c:\windows\SysWow64`. If I am right, you might miss other MS VC++ DLLs as well, even if you didn't notice this yet.

For example, virus scanners might block setup software from installing anything in the Windows system directories, or might consider that DLL as being hostile. Hence, I first would try to temporarily disable the virus scanner and execute the setup program for both variants (32-bit and 64-bit) of the VC++ 2012 runtime. You can download the both variants from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) (that file is from Visual C++ 2012).

If the setup programs refuse to install the runtime because it is already installed, try to uninstall the current versions first, then run the setup programs again.

While the virus scanner is still disabled, check whether the DLLs in question now are in `c:\windows\system32` and `c:\windows\SysWow64`, respectively. Then re-enable the virus scanner and try to start the problematic application(s). If the error still occurs, check again that the files still exist in the Windows system directories. If they don't, the virus scanner has removed them from there when you have re-enabled it or when an application wanted to access them. In this case, you would have to whitelist the files in your virus scanner.

If you don't find (or remember) a setting or software component which prevents those files from being copied into the Windows system directories, you could apply a more "manual" method: From the page I linked above you can download `vcredist_x86.exe` and `vcredist_x64.exe`. Although both files are executables, you can unpack them manually (without running them). For example, the [WiX toolset](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/) can do this, at least with the 2012 version you are interested in, and there are probably a few other packers capable of doing this.

After having unpacked those executables, you will see the DLLs you are after in the folder where you unpacked them. From there, copy them manually into the respective Windows system directory and try whether you now can start your problematic applications. Once again, if you can see the files in the Windows system directories immediately after having copied them, but they vanish later, you would have to find out which software component or setting on your system causes them being removed.

Answer (score 0):

Because that VS is not installing both Architectures of the redistribution package.
Install both (x86 and x64) and your problem will be gone.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679#

Comment: I can't, if I launch the x86 install I only get "repair" or "uninstall" options

Comment: are you running vcredist_x86.exe on a PC that already has the x86 version installed? You should run the the missing version on the PC that presents the dll error

Comment: I have only one machine the one with the dll error on which I already installed `vcredist_x64.exe`

Comment: then please check which dll is missing; the 64 bit will be under `\Windows\System32` and the 32 bit will be under `\Windows\SysWOW64`. if running vcredist_x86.exe you get "repair" and "uninstall" options try repairing and/or the uninstall/install sequence

Answer (score 0):

In many cases the best way to ensure that `MSVCR110.dll` will be found by the
application, is to copy it to the same folder as that of the executable.
This is what I do when nothing else works.

Note that there are two versions of the DLL: 64-bit and 32-bit.
You should use the DLL version having the same architecture as that of the
executable.

Many products come with the right DLL already installed in their folder,
so as to be independent of the version that is installed (or not installed).
Check if the problematic product has this DLL in some of its installation
folders.

Answer (score 0):

Try running  `sfc /scannow`, then reinstall * Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 update 4* both 32 and 64 bit, if it asks you to uninstall do it and then reinstall it again. You might also need to reinstall the application. Coping the missing dlls (msvcp*.dll and msvr*.dll)  to **System32** or **SysWOW64** might help.